# SQL Average always returns 0

Tags: sql

I have a simple `SQL` command:

```
SELECT Avg('observations1') AS AvgFeedback,
       Avg('observations2') AS AvgChallenge,
       Avg('observations3') AS AvgTalk,
       Avg('observations4') AS AvgSkills,
       Avg('observations5') AS AvgExpectations
FROM   .observations
WHERE  obsschool = 'admin';
```

However every result is 0 when there are numbers in each of the fields. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You should use a `GROUP BY` to have an average value between several rows. Unless you want the value of the field, but then you can remove the AVG function.

Comment: What are the datatypes for all observations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the quotes (`'`) wrapping your field names:

```
SELECT Avg(observations1) AS AvgFeedback,
       Avg(observations2) AS AvgChallenge,
       Avg(observations3) AS AvgTalk,
       Avg(observations4) AS AvgSkills,
       Avg(observations5) AS AvgExpectations
FROM   observations
WHERE  obsschool = 'admin';
```

When passing field names, no quotes necessary.

Comment: That is, `'observations1'` is a string constant but `observations1` is the column name. However, this should error, not give zero if this is SQL Server

Comment: @gbn, it is valid in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see what results you get?:

```
avg(cast(observations1 as dec(7,5))) as AvgFeedback
```